# cast of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to C pointer type 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') requires a bridged cast

Tags: objective-c, casting, automatic-ref-counting

When converting an Objective-C program to a Objective-C ARC, I get the error:

```
"cast of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to C pointer type 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') requires a bridged cast "
```

The code is as follows:

```
- (NSString *)_encodeString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, 
                                   (CFStringRef)string, // this is line in error
                                   NULL, 
                                   (CFStringRef)@";/?:@&=$+{}<>,",
                                   kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
    return [result autorelease];
}
```

What is a bridged cast?

[image: Screenshot for error]

Comment: Here is [a nice ARC tutorial](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2011-09-30-automatic-reference-counting.html) that I found to be easier to understand than Apple's documentation that @jtbandes references. Take a look at the section titled "Toll free bridging" in particular.

Comment: You can use '_bridge' or 'CFBridgingRetain' to resolve this error.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Have a look at the [ARC documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#bridged-casts) on the LLVM website. You'll have to use `__bridge` or one of the other keywords.

This is because Core Foundation objects (CF*Refs) are not controlled by ARC, only Obj-C objects are. So when you convert between them, you have to tell ARC about the object's ownership so it can properly clean them up. The simplest case is a `__bridge` cast, for which ARC will not do any extra work (it assumes you handle the object's memory yourself).

Comment: Thanks, understand.. and the link ont he ARC Documentation was very helpful on the type of __bridge cast to use.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is an old thread, I came across this issue while I need to use

```
- (NSString *)URLEncodedString 
{
    NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                                       (CFStringRef)self,
                                                                       NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"),
                                                                       kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
[result autorelease];
return result;
}
```

So what I did is go to **Target > Build phase > Compile sources**.
There is your file listed, double click on that and add following lines next to your file.

```
-fno-objc-arc
```