# Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer is disallowed with ARC

Tags: c++, objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, chipmunk

I'm playing around with this [Chipmunk Tutorial](http://www.alexandre-gomes.com/articles/chipmunk/) and I'm running into a problem with the following code (in section 5):

```
// Create our shape associated with the ball's body    
cpShape *ballShape = cpCircleShapeNew(ballBody, 20.0, cpvzero);  
ballShape->e = 0.5; // Elasticity  
ballShape->u = 0.8; // Friction  
ballShape->data = ball; // Associate with out ball's UIImageView
```

In the final line ballShape->data = ball; I'm trying to link the data property of the ballShape object with the UIImageView object ball.  If I turn off ARC processing this works fine, but with ARC I can't do this, getting the error:

```
"Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'cpDataPointer' (aka 'void *') is disallowed with ARC"
```

Since ballShape is a pointer, and the original object has a data property, is there any way I can assign the ball object to that property and make ARC happy?  I'm trying the following code:

```
ballShape->data = (__bridge cpDataPointer)ball; // Associate with out ball's UIImageView
```

This makes the error vanish but is this the correct fix for this problem?  I've looked at Apple's ARC documentation but a lot of it is pretty much over my head at the moment.  Sorry in advance if this is a pretty basic question, but the "->" operator in C confuses and angers me. :)

Comment: The first answer to this question explains bridge casting fairly well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725558/cast-of-objective-c-pointer-type-nsstring-to-c-pointer-type-cfstringref-a

Comment: Also, if you understand pointers, the C++ `->` operator isn't anything fancy. `ballShape->e` is the equivalent of `(*ballShape).e`.

Comment: ARC is Objective C - why is this tagged C++ (or C)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to store pointer, it is correct as long as you keep your reference to your `ball`.