# XCODE incompatible pointer type error

Tags: iphone, xcode, casting

I am getting a casting error.  My app is reading a text file from a webpage using 'stringWithContentsOfURL' method.  I want to parse the individual lines into separate components.  This is a snippet of the code.

```
  int parameterFive_1   = 0;
  parameterFive_1_range = NSMakeRange(0,10)
  lines                 = [response componentsSeparatedByString:@"\r"];

  parameterFive_1 = CFStringGetIntValue([[lines objectAtIndex:i] substringWithRange:parameterFive_1_range]);
```

I am getting the following error message:
" Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') is disallowed with ARC"

I thought it might be the compiler option but changing it to the default is not making a difference. Can anyone provide any insight?

Comment: possible duplicate of [cast of Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' to C pointer type 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') requires a bridged cast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725558/cast-of-objective-c-pointer-type-nsstring-to-c-pointer-type-cfstringref-a)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just cast the NSString* to CFStringRef to satisfy ARC:

```
parameterFive_1 = CFStringGetIntValue((__bridge CFStringRef)[[lines objectAtIndex:i] substringWithRange:parameterFive_1_range]);
```

The `__bridge` keyword here lets ARC know that it doesn't need to transfer ownership of the string.