# Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type. Bridged cast issue

Tags: objective-c, ios, pointers, types

I'm getting the following error:

```
"Implicit conversion of Objective-C pointer type. Type "void*" requires a bridged cast.
```

I've fixed similar bits of code with bridges - but those types of fixes are not helping here. Here's the bits of code :

```
AURenderCallbackStruct input;
input.inputProc = RenderTone;
input.inputProcRefCon = self;
err = AudioUnitSetProperty(
    toneUnit, 
    kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback, 
    kAudioUnitScope_Input,
    0, 
    &input, 
    sizeof(input));
NSAssert1(err == noErr, @"Error setting callback: %ld", err);
```

**Second code bit with error**

```
SStatus result = AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, ToneInterruptionListener, self);
if (result == kAudioSessionNoError) {
    UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
    AudioSessionSetProperty(
        kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory,
        sizeof(sessionCategory),
        &sessionCategory);
}
```

Thanks, in advance for all help.

**Update**

Problem solved. The bridge casting was being implemented incorrectly. It should have been :

```
 input. inputProcRefCon =  (__bridge void*)self
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified!

On the first bit of code it's on line 3, on the second bit of code it's on line 1.

Comment: take a look at this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725558/cast-of-objective-c-pointer-type-nsstring-to-c-pointer-type-cfstringref-a

Comment: Can't seem to solve it with the bridge at all. ty anyway

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as correct, so that it doesn't show this question on 'unanswered' anymore.