# Apportable - Is -objc-arc supported?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, apportable

I've a project with a bunch of files tagged as "-objc-arc" but when compiling with apportable I have tons of errors like: `error: cast of C pointer type 'CFStringRef' (aka 'const struct __CFString *') to Objective-C pointer type 'NSString *' requires a bridged cast`
which I suspect is coming from the lack of support of the "objc-arc" flag. Did I miss something?

[EDIT] I missed to tell that I'm talking about compiling code with "Apportable" SDK/Compiler

Comment: No, conversely, the the compiler only complains for stuff like this in ARC mode. Turn that off.

Answer (score 6):

The clang compiler in the Apportable SDK compiles files with or without the objc-arc, just as is specified in the xcode project.

The issue is likely that you are using an older, less strict version of clang with xcode. If you add the bridged casts, your code should work now with Apportable and with upcoming versions of xcode.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725558/cast-of-objective-c-pointer-type-nsstring-to-c-pointer-type-cfstringref-a) for more about why the bridged casts are needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's a lot of trouble to get my code compile without error on Apportable. I'm getting more and more errors each time I step further, and I think I will stop my experiment with it as I even don't know if it's worth all the work to make it compile. I'm feeling it's more a waste of time.